# Why << method explicitly returns self helps method chaining?

Tags: ruby

I am reading Programming Ruby charpter of expressions.

```
class ScoreKeeper
  def initialize
    @total_score = @count = 0
  end
  def <<(score)
    @total_score += score
    @count += 1
    self
  end
  def average
    fail "No scores" if @count.zero?
    Float(@total_score) / @count
  end
end

scores = ScoreKeeper.new
scores << 10 << 20 << 40
puts "Average = #{scores.average}"
```

This produces

```
Average = 23.333333333333332
```

The book expains

> Note that there’s a subtlety in this code—the << method explicitly
>   returns self. It does this to allow the method chaining in the line
>   scores << 10 << 20 << 40. Because each call to << returns the scores
>   object, you can then call << again, passing in a new score.

I still do not understand why return self to allow method chaining.
Anybody could help?

Comment: Have you tried to remove that `self` from `def <<`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would not have returned `self` after `@count += 1`, having written `scores << 2 << 1` you would end up in an error saying

```
undefined method << for Fixnum
```

This

```
scores = ScoreKeeper.new
scores << 10 << 20
```

works because `scores << 10` returns the receiver, i.e. the object which has defined method `<<` on it, eg `scores`. So it is possible to chain method calls.

Without `self` you would not be able to chain method calls, because the return value of `<<` method would be a number.

## EDIT

As per comment by **Jörg W Mittag** (assuming you are on Ruby 2.4.x):

> Actually, it's even worse: [`<<` is defined for `Integer`s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_preview2/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C), so you will not
>   get an error, but rather a non-obviously wrong result. (Or more
>   precisely, you will get an error later, when trying to call the
>   non-existing `Integer#average` method.)

Comment: "and scores is an instance of ScoreKeeper because you return self" - these two facts have no relation between them. :)

Comment: Not only `scores` is a `ScoreKeeper`, but `scores << 10` is a `ScoreKeeper` too. That's the prerequisite for chaining. I know you know this. Just want to improve the wording here :)

Comment: Still I felt the need to improve further. Hope you find my edit acceptable :)

Comment: Actually, it's even worse: [`<<` *is* defined for `Integer`s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_preview2/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C), so you will *not* get an error, but rather a non-obviously wrong result. (Or more precisely, you will get an error *later*, when trying to call the non-existing `Integer#average` method.)